# how to serve php files on a Apache server (localhost) running Coldfusion/MySql?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, localhost, coldfusion

I'm still learning my ways around on my localhost server, whih is running Apache 2.2, Coldfusion8 and MySQL Server 5.5 (on Windows XP).

I need to work on a site I inherited, which also ran some PHP scripts under the same setup. I have installed PHP5 on my localhost, but when I open a dummy page with:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

I only get plain text returned, so I guess I haven't configured Apache correctly to also serve PHP (while defaulting to Coldfusion).

**Question:**
Where do I need to get started if I want PHP to work on my current setup, too? Is there something I need to add to the httpd.conf file? If possible I don't want to uninstall/reinstall everything, because it took forever to get everything to work (excluding php).

Thanks for any pointers!

**EDIT**:
Added this to my httpd.conf:

```
AddType Application/x-httpd-php .php 
LoadModule php5_module "c:/programme/php/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

and restarted Apache. Nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Uninstall/Reinstall PHP worked...

This was helpful in case anyone else runs into the same:

[Installing and Configuring PHP/Apache/MySQL](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-windows.html#installPHPEngine) (sans CF)